# Play Java 2.1.1 "TimeoutException: No response received after... "

Tags: java, web-services, playframework, timeout

I have this code in my controller:

```
public static Result index() {
    return async(WS.url(MY_WEBSERVICE_URL).get().map(
        new Function<WS.Response, Result>() {
            public Result apply(WS.Response response) {
                return ok(index.render(form(response.getBody()));
            }
        }
    );
}
```

Basically, it's copy from example on [play site](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.x/JavaWS)
I'm receiving this message

> [TimeoutException: No response received after 2147483647]

After around **1 minute**, and even if I have set

> WS.url(MY_WEBSERVICE_URL).setTimeout(Integer.MAX_VALUE)

or add

> ws.timeout=99999999999

in application.conf.

I saw similar post here, but it also was without answer.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Problem was **magically ** resolved after creating new project and pasting this code.